# Setup secure connection with nginx and startssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I've registered on startssl.com and so retrivied 4 files for my domain:

- ssl.key - *the private key file*
- ssl.crt - *the certificate file*
- ca.pem - *Root CA*
- sub.class1.server.ca.pem - *Class 1 Intermediate Server CA certificate*

to remove password i did:

```
openssl rsa -in ssl.key -out ssl.key.nopwd
```

Then, I set up my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key.nopwd;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    fastcgi_param SSL_VERIFIED $ssl_client_verify;
    fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_SERIAL $ssl_client_serial;
    fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_cert;
    fastcgi_param SSL_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;

    server_name ***;
    root /var/www/***;
}
```

After nginx restarted I can successfully enter to my site via https.
But now I want to secure my site and give access to it only with certificate, installed in a client browser. As I understand I must setup it in nginx config:

```
ssl_client_certificate    etc/nginx/ssl/[WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE?]
ssl_verify_client         on;
```

But what file should I point to? How can I generate a client certificate from the server one?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/714160/nginx-client-ssl-authentication/715150#715150). But here is the short version of what needs to happen:

1. Using `ssl.crt` as is is not good enough, you should concatenate ssl.crt + intermediate CA(s) + Root CA (in this order) into a single file and use this file in `ssl_certificate` statement.
2. You need to consolidate Intermediate CA(s) + Root CA of your **CLIENT** certificate in a single file and adding it in `ssl_client_cerificate` statement.
3. Optional but highly recommended, set up rule what client certificate subject names you require (i.e. CN, O, OU, DC, etc.) by analyzing `$ssl_client_s_dn` variable.
4. It is also highly recommended to enable OSCP stapling by combining Intermediate CA(s) + Root CA of your **SERVER** and adding it to  `ssl_trusted_certificate` statement as follows:

   ```
   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ocsp-chain.crt;
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;
   ```
5. You may also want to pass certificate info to your fastcgi module:

   ```
   ...
   fastcgi_param   VERIFIED $ssl_client_verify;
   fastcgi_param   DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
   ...
   ```

Comment: ok I did `cat ssl.crt sub.class1.server.ca.pem ca.pem > server.crt` and updated nginx config with `ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;`. Also I did `cat sub.class1.server.ca.pem ca.pem > client.crt` and so updated nginx config with `ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client.crt;`. To the config file I've added `ssl_verify_client on;` But now I get error: `400 Bad Request The SSL certificate error` in the biowser while trying to connect. Didi I miss something?

Comment: You messed up the client certificate - you put there chain from your server certificate but the `client.crt` should contain CA chain of your client certificate. If it is self signed then it has to be the client certificate itself.

Comment: still can't catch that. all I have are these 4 files from startssl and all I need is to make secure connection with a certificate to nginx site. Should I create a client certificate from the server one? Or I need to create a certificate with openssl and then sign it with server the server one? I'm really confused

Comment: How did you create the client certificate?